# Proper way to upgrade jquery UI library

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on to upgrade javascript libraries due to some vulnerability concern. The one I am stuck right now is JQuery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js. I need to upgrade it to Jquery-ui-1.12.0.js but I am not sure if the regular Jquery-UI-1.12 file could replace this custom file. This is an old project .NET project. I am not sure whats the difference between the regular and custom files. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I believe the `.custom` is added when only some of the library has been bundled into the file (e.g. where some items are un-ticked on the download page https://jqueryui.com/download/ ) In theory you should be able to replace the `JQuery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js` with a `JQuery-ui-1.10.1.js` with no issues, it will simply add some unused library code. Though I can't comment on the upgrade path.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to be sure that upgrading won't break your app is your tests. If you don't have a testing strategy, you'll need to adopt one. When your code is well covered, you'll be able to swap the jQuery libs and know right away if something is breaking.

[Software Testing approaches](https://codeutopia.net/blog/2015/03/01/unit-testing-tdd-and-bdd/)

https://jqueryui.com/changelog/1.11.1/

https://jqueryui.com/changelog/1.11.2/

Comment: This is an old application with no test coverage at all and I am pretty sure adding testing strategy is not on Todo list right now.

Comment: In that case, the next best(though far from ideal) thing is to go through the changelogs and CTRL+F any affected items against your codebase to identify any possible points of failure - Edited my post